Apollo Angular - Bypassing Interceptors
Currently using Apollo Angular for graphql needs.
As part of the project there is a need to make queries/mutations which bypass the interceptors we have in place.
Our previous solution without Apollo we just instantiated a new HttpBackend which bypasses the interceptors stage, we are trying to figure out if its possible to do something similar with Apollo Angular and if yes how?
Thanks in advance.

from what I checked its a feature request, maybe raise a request on their github page! else you need to skip these specific calls, maybe check eliseo answer here
